# Trying to wevscrape, but data comes out with extra details (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Currently using Python 3 and importing BeautifulSoup,

When I code in

```
for property in content:
print(property.find('a').text) 
print(property.find('span').text)
```

The code prints out the proper details, with the name of 'a' property and 'span' property

- 'a property name'
- 'span' property name

However, when I try to create a `serviceList = []`
followed by:

```
for property in content:
name = property.find('a').text 
details = property.find('span').text

serviceList = {
    'Name' : name,
    " /// "
    'Details' : details
}
```

- 'a property name'
- 'span' property name\xa0\xa0(rest of 'span' property)

How come I'm getting that extra \xa0\xa0 on my output?

Forgive the formatting, I'm rather new here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you print text with `\xa0`, it prints it as a space, but the special characters is still there.

You can remove it with, for example, with `unicodedata` module:

```
import unicodedata

text = 'This\xa0Is\xa0Text'

text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text)
print([text])
```

Removes `\xa0`:

```
['This Is Text']
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the help, this makes sense. (Somewhat considering my absolute novice abilities)

I'm uncertain how to apply this to my code.

This issue only appears only if I put in the pageList { part of my code. Any advice for this and future possible occurrences regarding this?